# Mysql:Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, database

First of all, i know there are many posts about this subject but the ones i checked didnt help me so i wanted to post my problem.

I am building a website that people can register as user then fill some different forms for me. I have 2 table one is "user" and the other one is "form" table. In user table i have user_id which is auto_incremented and this id connected to "form" table as foreign key. I want to see which user filled forms via user_id. When i try to register filled form to database i get "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" message. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the user_id on on your form table as a foreign key pointing at the user_id in the user table, you must supply a valid user_id when you insert the form row.

You could set the user_id field on the form table to be allowed to be NULL this will mean it does not have to be set.

Comment: ALTER TABLE  `form` CHANGE  `user_id`  `user_id` INT( 5 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL

MySQL output: 

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'user_id'

Comment: "NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL" this doesn't look correct to me.better if you could paste your table structure and query which you are trying to insert/update it.

Comment: mysql_query("CREATE TABLE kullanici (

 user_id int(5) NULL,
 user_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
 E_Mail VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 Skype_name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,

 
 PRIMARY KEY (user_name,user_id))");
 

 
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE form (

 form_name VARCHAR(20) NULL,
 form_id int(2) NULL ,
 Kule int(2) NOT NULL,
 Silahhane int(2) NULL,
 Han int(2) NULL,
 Kutuphane int(2) NULL,

 
)");       i add foreign keys in phpmyadmin not directly.

Comment: your primary key should not be NULL. this [link](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqltables.php) will help you to understand the concept.

Comment: nope it didnt work. i re-created the table "user" and set the value "not NULL" but same problem occured. when i remove the foreign keys it works. crap...

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add some data to your foreign key column that there is no same data in other table .

Comment: It is suppose to take user_id automatically from user table because it is foreign key ,isnt it ?

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens **when there is a data in table** and you want to create/ edit/ delete a foreign_key 
 OR 
the field that you want to make it foreign_key is not the same format with Table field

solution:
You have to make a 

 1)backup or copy of you data 

 2)remove the foreign_keys 

 3)and Truncate data from table

 4)Finally re attach the foreign_keys

 5)update your data

I hope it helps